# sharing an IMAP mailbox

Tags: email, imap, postfix, share

How do you keep a mailbox available to a group of users, while making the mailbox behave like a mailing list?

I mean, when a user reads a message, this should be not marked as read for anyone. This is much like a mailing list, but the people in the group should be able to send using the mailbox address as a regular account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dovecot as IMAP server, you can enable its acl plugin for mailbox sharing. Reference: http://wiki.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes

If you are using iRedMail, a free and open source mail server bundle, it's easy to achieve: http://www.iredmail.org/wiki/index.php?title=IRedMail/FAQ/Share.IMAP.Folder